# jquery - Run a callback when an array of promises is successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I have an array of promises, and I'm trying to add a callback that will be executed when all of these are successful. This is the prime use cases for the jQuery `$.when()`, but somehow it's not working.

I have this code running for several different ajax queries:

```
// Global variable that holds the promises
var dygraph_promises = []

var plot_promise = $.ajax()
plot_promise.done(function(a) {
      console.log("DONE!");
      // do stuff with data
});

// Keep track of promises
dygraph_promises.push(plot_promise);
```

Then I want to run the following code when everything is done

```
// Synchronize dygraphs together
console.log(dygraph_promises);
console.log(dygraph_promises.length);
$.when.apply($, dygraph_promises)
   .then(function() {
       console.log("when called!");
   });
```

When I run this code in my console, I see the string `"when called"` printed before the strings `"DONE"`. So the `when` fires before all the calls are completed..

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Can't reproduce -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/dd4wq0b6/

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'm actually not using `$.ajax()` but a library that wraps around it (influxdb-js). The object returned doesn't have the same fields as the object returned by `$.ajax()` though. I'll update the question accordingly

Comment: Uhm, you can't use `$.when` on something that isn't jQuery ?

Comment: When I look at the object returned by that call, I see these fields: `n { then=function(),  done=function(),  nodeify=function()}`. I thought this was a standard promise/deferred, and therefore that I could use jQuery. But the content doesn't match the fields returned by `$.ajax()`. Any idea what this is?

Comment: All promises are "thenable", so they return somewhat the same properties, but currently I think jQuery's `$.when` only supports jQuery's promises, which incidentally don't follow the A+ standard.

Comment: Any ideas what type of promise this can be, and what function I should use instead of `$.when` to get the same functionality?

Comment: $.when(dygraph_promises).then(...)?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help of @adeneo, I found out that I wasn't using standard jQuery promises. As a result, I start using the [q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/) library, and using the `all` call [there](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall)

```
Q.all(dygraph_promises)
   .then(function(a) {
     ...
   )};
```

Comment: Please accept your answer if it is OK, so that other users don't come to that question and try to help you ;)